# Incorrect Team ID in Turn Context from MS Teams?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm using the bot builder to make an action-based messaging extension. I want to get the team's group ID, so I can use the group with the graph API, however I'm having trouble getting that ID.

In my OnTurnAsync method, turnContext has Activity.ChannelData that looks like this:

```
{
  "channel": {
    "id": "19:b7082f7e8a2547d49e0c730b9566fded@thread.skype"
  },
  "team": {
    "id": "19:b7082f7e8a2547d49e0c730b9566fded@thread.skype"
  },
  "tenant": {
    "id": "542f825f-b8d2-4170-8b2b-3524de6143bd"
  },
  "source": {
    "name": "compose"
  }
}
```

Is it correct for the team id to be the same as the channel id? How do I get the group ID that I can use to interact with the team's group in the graph API from the information I have in the OnTurnAsync method?